# Interpret an indicator function for a uniform random variable $I_{(x,\infty)}$

Tags: probability, notation

I'm trying to parse an indicator variable.  I thought I understood them, but this is baffling me. A density function is given as

$$f(x;\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}I_{(x,\infty)}(\theta)$$

and $\theta > 0$.  It is supposed to be a uniform distribution, but how?  That indicator function should be $1$ precisely when $x < \theta < \infty$ if I understand it right.  But that would be bounding $\theta$, not $x$.

But then what is the domain of this thing? In what variables?

If it were uniform on $[0, \theta]$ for example, then the $\frac{1}{\theta}$ would make sense, but what is the indicator function actually saying?  What are the bounds on $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $x>0$. The indicator function gives you boundaries for both $\theta$ and $x$ at the same time, for $x<\theta$. You could write the indicator function for $x$ as $I_{(0,\theta)}(x)$. However, maybe your problem is more focused on the parameter. I've seen this kind of problems in statistical inference when you have a random sample of a $Uniform(0,\theta)$.